# How to aggregate data by its attributes(large data set)?

Tags: excel, vba, bigdata

I currently have a large set of data in excel (600,000 lines long).
What I have is the generation of a certain plant in all different states, what I want to do is have the total generation of a state. What is a quick way of aggregating the individual plant data into state data.

I have provided a very small example of what I have here:

[image: example data]

The main challenge is that my table with the AA1=QLD is a separate document and not as simple as in my example, in reality there is over 50 different plants for each state and no naming patterns for the plants.

The only thing I think that would solve this for me is writing an iff statement about 400 lines long, which of course, is not feasible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First transfer your document to a table:

[image]

Then add a helper column that lines up the correct state with the correct plant in the table.  A simple VLOOKUP will do this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,I:J,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Then insert a pivot table using the data from the existing table and new helper column.  Put `State` in Rows and `Generation` in Values

[image]